# is there a way to show the Django debug stacktrace page to admin users even if DEBUG=False in settings?

Tags: django

Scenario:  instead of me having to SSH into a box to retrieve a stacktrace, I'd prefer non-techie co-workers to just email me the error!

Is there a way or hook in Django to do something like this?  e.g.

```
def 500_error_happened(request):    # psuedocode >__<
    if request.user.is_staff:
        show_the_debug_stack_trace_page()
    else:
        show_user_friendly_500_html_page()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found an answer!   You can use a middleware which displays `technical_500_response` to superusers:

```
from django.views.debug import technical_500_response
import sys

class UserBasedExceptionMiddleware(object):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return technical_500_response(request, *sys.exc_info())
```

(from https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/935/)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look into Sentry:

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry

With that, you can record the errors and stacktraces you would usually see with DEBUG=True, aggregate them and take a deeper look into them. Sentry can be configured to send emails to you so that you are notified instantly.

Another option that does not require a new dependency would be to use the `AdminEmailHandler`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler

However, some information you might need for debugging may be sensitive and should not be sent via email. This is why even the Django docs mentioned above recommend using something like Sentry.

Comment: good answer, I would change the order of your suggestions as sentry requires the setup of another service while the AdminEmailHandler only assumes Django to be able to send emails :)