# Switch on django error page only for admins when debug = False

Tags: python, django

It is a copy of:
[is there a way to show the Django debug stacktrace page to admin users even if DEBUG=False in settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604870/is-there-a-way-to-show-the-debug-stacktrace-page-to-admin-users-even-if-debug-fa)
but there is no answer

How to show django error page with stacktrace when debug=False only for admin users.
I don't want to use sentry.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/

Comment: @karthikr did you read the link?  I didn't see anything there that answered his question, at least as how I interpretted it

Comment: Seriously? The title and the first line in the link is not enough to understand it??

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find an answer in the first line. I need to see errors in realtime when debug is False for admins only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find an answer

In urls.py add

```
handler404 = 'site_utils.handler404'
```

Create site_utils.py in the same folder where urls.py and add there

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect,  HttpResponsePermanentRedirect
import sys
from django.views.debug import technical_404_response, technical_500_response 
def handler404(request):
    if (request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff) or request.user.is_superuser:
        exc_type, exc_value, tb = sys.exc_info()
        return technical_404_response(request, exc_value)
    else:
        return  HttpResponsePermanentRedirect("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is incredibly insecure, which is likely why Django provides no default way to do this. Running DEBUG on a production app can expose your SETTINGS file  (including API tokens) to the world.

If you really want to do this, take a look at `django.views.debug.technical_500_response` and write a [custom exception handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process_exception) that returns the value from there.

Comment: How so?  In the default Django 500 error page all I see is "SECRET_KEY u'********************'"

Comment: It seems I was mistaken. By default, Django protects you against posting your secret key, and settings which it [deems inappropriate to display](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug). Its still a very bad idea to pass any form of debug information to any client. For instance, the debug information can display your DATABASES setup, which can lead to security vulnerabilities. You should likely be using [logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#an-example) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version for Django 3.2.

Save the following file in, for example, `mysite/debug.py`:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
from django.views.debug import technical_500_response
import sys

class UserBasedExceptionMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return technical_500_response(request, *sys.exc_info())
```

Update your `mysite/settings.py` as follows:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  ... whatever ...
  'mysite.debug.UserBasedExceptionMiddleware',
)
```